# Getting 'Python was not found' error when using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm currently doing a project trying to make an inventory management system using django. For that I wanted to use a virtual environment to get it up and running. Virtual Env works perfectly fine, allowing me to start a project `inventory_management` using django. However every time I write `python3 manage.py startapp inventory`, it says

`Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. I was following a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sWgionzDoM) to help me understand the basics... Could someone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Does this help? [Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings](/q/65348890/4518341). I don't use Windows myself so I'm not sure how useful this is, but I just googled the message and found it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research.

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: If you are in the virtual environment I expect the Python interpreter may be named *python.exe* rather than *python**3**.exe*.

Comment: It'd help to add a timestamp(s) for the relevant part(s) of the guide. It's 2 hours long. The command you're talking about occurs at [3:40](https://youtu.be/_sWgionzDoM?t=220)

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help. I did avtivate virtualenv, and no I didnt think the python interpreter woud be named python.exe. I will make the necessary changes and get back to to see if it works